# woocommerce doesn't show products on category page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I faced the wall. Woocommerce doesn't show the products on the category page. I used google and I didn't find the solution. Few days I've fought with this problem and nothing. I think I set everything correctly (print screens). The web address: http://demo-systems.com/product-category/walizki-plastikowe/

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like you are using multi language. Have you translated product and product category also?

Comment: At that moment I use for shop only one language PL. But WooCommerce is in EN :( It's any problem?

Comment: I've made PL localization for Woocommerce and now is everything in one language, but it doesn't work still :(